# Format numbered JSON list in HTML

Tags: html, json, knockout.js, html-lists

I have data that I'm returning as JSON as follows:

```
 {
"Text": "This is 1",
"Number": "1."
},
{
"Text": "This is 2 ",
"Number": "2."
 },
{
"Text": "This is 3 ",
"Number": "3."
},
{
"Text": "test indent",
"Number": "a."
 },
{
"Text": "test indent 2",
"Number": "b."
},
{
"Text": "insrt 1",
"Number": "i."
},
{
"Text": "back to indent ",
"Number": "c."
},
{
"Text": "This is 4 ",
"Number": "4."
}
```

I'm displaying it in HTML with knockout as follows:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: numberedList, visible: numberedList().length > 0">
<span data-bind="text: number"></span>
<span data-bind="html: text"></span><br />
</div>
```

What function / code to I need to add that the data should be indented according to the numbers / letters? I want the HTML page to look as follows:
[image]

Thank you

Comment: For indentation you can simply use CSS

Comment: there's a way to specify in CSS to align the different numbers in a list (a, 1, i, etc)? Thanks

Comment: Show a sample how you wanna align different numbers in your view.

Comment: I added how I want to align the numbers. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to implement what you wanna do you need to modify the structure of your data. There is no relation between your current data and implementing such a thing with that data would be kind of messy.

Here is an example how your data might be :https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/76/

**HTML :**

```
<div data-bind="foreach:Items">
  <span data-bind="text:Number"></span><span data-bind="text:Text"></span>
  <div data-bind="foreach:Children">
     <div class="sub-1">
         <span data-bind="text:Number"></span><span data-bind="text:Text"></span>
     </div>
     <div data-bind="foreach:Children">
        <div class="sub-2">
           <span data-bind="text:Number"></span><span data-bind="text:Text"></span>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
data =  [
   {
      "Text":"This is 1",
      "Number":"1.",
      "Children":[]
   },
   {
      "Text":"This is 2",
      "Number":"2.",
      "Children":[]
   },
   {
      "Text":"This is 3",
      "Number":"3.",
      "Children":[
         {
            "Text":"test indent",
            "Number":"a.",
            "Children":[]
         },
         {
            "Text":"test indent 2",
            "Number":"b.",
            "Children":[
               {
                  "Text":"insert i",
                  "Number":"i.",
                  "Children":[]
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "Text":"back to indent",
            "Number":"c.",
            "Children":[

            ]
         },

      ]
   }
]
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Items = ko.observableArray(data);
}
var VM = new AppViewModel()
ko.applyBindings(VM);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply - there can be up to 4 sublevels - does that mean I would have to do 4 loops - I thought it would be nice if I can just put one loop for everything, but if the data is messy like that then I'll restructure it.

Comment: if you want to put them all in one loop then you need to have a relation between your data like `id` , `parentId` but again you will have some if statements inside a loop in order to apply right data with a right class for indentation by using those relations (id,parent-id) . If you look at nested loops complexity,  a `big-O notation` is typically (not always) is O(n²). Mathematically we can say that it will execute n² times in worse case but `Big-O` doesn't always measure exactly how much work is being done. It is up to you which one to go with , I would go with nested loops.

Comment: nested loops does seem to make more sense for me. I will update my data structure. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it in css using class names. If  you want the nesting to determine the type, you can replace the classnames for `ol > ol` type selectors.

```css
ol.alpha {
  counter-reset: alphalist;
}

ol.alpha > li {
  list-style: none;
}

ol.alpha > li::before {
  content: counter(alphalist, lower-alpha)". ";
  counter-increment: alphalist;
}


ol.roman {
  counter-reset: romanlist;
}

ol.roman > li {
  list-style: none;
}

ol.roman > li::before {
  content: counter(romanlist, lower-roman)". ";
  counter-increment: romanlist;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>
    Item 2
    <ol class="alpha">
      <li>Item A</li>
      <li>
        Item B
        <ol class="roman">
          <li>Item I</li>
          <li>Item II</li>
        </ol>
      </li>

      <li>Item C</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the issue by me is that it's in one list, and I needed to put it in one list in the code

Answer (score -1):

I would make a variable to push that json in it.

`var data = [];
data.push({"Text": "This is 1","Number": "1."});`

and then I would make a function to return it to the screen.
you have to show some work as well, try it and show what kind of function you are trying to make , the MDN is a good place to look up info.